# Magento 2 How to load Js first before the page load

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, cms-pages, home, requirejs-config.js

I have created a custom module in which I created a popup modal in custom location.js with require js on and add this js in default.xml file.

On the first page load popup is open after the page load i want to load this js before the page load.

Here's the default.xml wihich I override

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
  <link src="Vendor_Module::js/location.js"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-block-name" template="Vendor_Module::popup.phtml" ifconfig="nearbyproducts/general/enable"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Can you please suggest how can I load js before page load or stop the page load?

Comment: Hi Divya, your question is bit unclear for me. Can you elaborate a little more? what is your js file actually trying to do? I dont think stopping page load for a js file is a good idea. Javascript files are by default blockers during page load unless you make them async.

Comment: Hi there , can you please share the script here ? I am guessing you could move your script in the head tag and write events that when a dom element is loaded it could trigger.

Comment: Hi @RajeevKTomy, I created a Zipcode popup in js file when we enter zipcode then products will be come according to distance.

Comment: Hi @RajeevKTomy, Issue is that In catalog product page when I enter zipcode product are come from cache they will not short and after clean the cache product will show correctly.
I hope it's clear for you.